# where is Async.BuildPrimitive and Async.Spawn defined?

Tags: f#

Working through Expert F# and it uses some examples that use Async.BuildPrimitive and Async.Spawn however they are undefined. I am using .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Library API was changed since publishing the first edition of "Expert F#"

> Async.BuildPrimitive ->
>   Async.FromBeginEnd
>
> Async.Spawn -> Async.Start

Comment: I think `BuildPrimitive` is now `FromBeginEnd`.